# SignalR BackPlane

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-backplane

I have implemented SignalR BackPlane and it seems to be working fine.

Have used this [URL](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server) for reference.

I am creating a new SQL Database to achieve SingalR. My Doubt is: why do I have to create a new DB, or why can't I make use of existing Database?

1. Can I use the existing DB to achieve the same rather than creating new DB?
2. What SQL permissions have to be taken care of to create a new table in an existing DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same DB , however for performance it is better to have DB with Service Broker enabled.
(That is why I have a seperate DB for my singlR use cases)

Permissions:

"Requires CREATE TABLE permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the table is being created."

Taken from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188264.aspx

Comment: Yep , we can create in the same DB , but we have to take care of additional permission. If we mess up even an single permission it wont work.